# Prove prime $p$ divides $\binom{p^k}{n}$ for any $n$, $1 \le n \le p^k-1$, $k$ a positive integer

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, combinatorial-proofs, combinatorial-number-theory

I have got 
$$\binom{p^k}{n} = \cfrac{p^k}{n} \binom{p^k-1}{n-1}=p\biggl[\cfrac{p^{k-1}}{n}\binom{p^k-1}{n-1}\biggl]$$
The first approach is to show that the term in the square bracket is also an integer. I know that $\binom{p^k-1}{n-1}$ is an integer, but how should I deal with $\frac{p^{k-1}}{n}$?

The second approach is from $$\binom{p^k}{n} = \cfrac{p^k}{n} \binom{p^k-1}{n-1}$$ 
we get$$n\binom{p^k}{n} = p^k\binom{p^k-1}{n-1}$$ Thus$$p^k \biggl| n\binom{p^k}{n}$$ Then we divide into two cases:
1) Suppose $gcd(p^k, n) = 1$, then by Euclid's lemma, we know $p^k\bigl|\binom{p^k}{n}$ and thus $p\bigl|\binom{p^k}{n}$.
2) Suppose $gcd(p^k, n) > 1$, then $p^k$ and $n$ have common divisors. Let $m$ be the product of all common divisors of $p^k$ and $n$, then $gcd(\frac{p^k}{m}, \frac{n}{m}) = 1$. From $\frac{p^k}{m} \bigl| \frac{n}{m}\binom{p^k}{n}$, we have $\frac{p^k}{m}\bigl|\binom{p^k}{n}$ where $\frac{p^k}{m}$ is an integer. How can I proceed from here?

Or is there any other approach? Thanks.

Comment: You can see that $pot_p(n)\le k-1$

Comment: Maybe investigating the expression $\frac{p^k !}{(p^k-n)!n!}$ can be worth it?

Comment: Taking $k=1$, $p=4$ and $n=2$, we have $\binom{p^k}{n} = \binom{4^1}{2} = \dfrac{4 \times 3}{2} = 6 $ and $4 \nmid 6$. You should add some more hypothesis to make the result true.

Comment: In general $\nu _p(\binom{p^k}{n})=k-\nu _p(n),$ where $\nu _p(a)$ is the maximum exponent of $p$ that  divides $n.$ You can attempt it using Legendre's formula.

Comment: It's easy using [Luca's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is even and $k=1$, you have $\binom{p}{2} = \dfrac{p(p-1)}{2} \in \mathbb{N}$. If $\dfrac{p(p-1)}{2} = l p$ for some $l$, we get $2l = p-1$ thus $p$ is odd. This is absurd. So, necessarily you have to take either $p$  odd or $k \neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $n \binom{p^k}{n} = p^k \binom{p^k - 1}{n-1}$ so $p^k$ divides $n \binom{p^k}{n}$.

First case: $ \textrm{gcd}(n, p) = 1$. So we also have $ \textrm{gcd}(n, p^k) = 1$. According to Gauss theorem, we have $p^k | \binom{p^k}{n}$ and then $p | \binom{p^k}{n}$.

Second case: $ \textrm{gcd}(n, p) \neq 1$. We write $p = qs$ and $n = ms$ with $ \textrm{gcd}(m, q) = 1$ and $\textrm{gcd}(n, p) = s \geq 2$. $n \binom{p^k}{n} = p^k \binom{p^k - 1}{n-1}$ becomes $m s \binom{p^k}{n} = q^k s^k \binom{p^k - 1}{n-1}$ then $m \binom{p^k}{n} = q^k  s^{k-1} \binom{p^k - 1}{n-1}$ so we get $q | \binom{p^k}{n}$. I do not know how to go further...

Comment: Why is p prime?

Comment: How do you get $gcd(n, p^k) = 1$ from $gcd(n,p) = 1$?

Comment: It is not right, but certainly an interesting idea:)

Comment: Writing the Bezout identity to the power $k$ and using the binom formula, and reorganizing the whole, we can obtain a Bezout identity with $n$ and $p^k$.

Comment: This is a good approach. I have added it to my question!